# How to overlay mean of a column with corresponding binwidth values in histogram in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

How can I insert the mean value of "ele" in the following histogram.

```
dput(dfsample)
structure(list(value = c(0.0335026912575717, 0.0345000229569703, 
 0.0354186209415201, 0.038902323373206, 0.0426493324589743, 0.0321982282442823, 
0.033229179855505, 0.0349933075439487, 0.036071015613386, 0.036286798879435
), ele = c(721L, 749L, 700L, 665L, 674L, 677L, 747L, 900L, 869L, 
774L)), .Names = c("value", "ele"), row.names = c(840L, 841L, 
842L, 843L, 844L, 833L, 834L, 835L, 836L, 837L), class = "data.frame")

p1<-ggplot(dfsample, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.01,fill="aquamarine4", colour="black")+
  geom_point(aes(y=ele))
p1
```

Here what I am trying to do is to insert the mean of "ele" that belongs to each binwidth and not all the "ele" points.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: How will this work? Note that a histogram plots counts (your example goes up to 8-ish) but `ele` is in the 600s or 700s, so even if you plot the mean `ele` for each bin on your histogram, the y axes are different, and the mean `ele` will be so high (600-700ish) that the histogram will appear like a flat line.

Answer (score 2):

You need to establish a grouping of the `ele` that corresponds the the bins created with `geom_histogram`.  You could do this with outside of the `ggplot` call using some method of aggregating the data.  Here is an example using `dplyr` to get the means of the histogram groups.  You may want to look at `stat_summary` as another option.

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(dfsample, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.01, fill="aquamarine4", colour="black")

## Get the histogram breaks
stuff <- ggplot_build(p1)
breaks <- with(stuff[[1]][[1]], c(xmin, xmax[length(xmax)]))
mids <- stuff[[1]][[1]]$x  # midpoints of bins

## use those to define the grouping to get means
dfsample$group <- cut(dfsample$value, breaks=breaks)
library(dplyr)
dfsample %>% group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(y=mean(ele)) %>%
  mutate(group = mids[as.integer(group)]) -> dat

## add the means as points
p1 + geom_point(data=dat, aes(group, y), color="red")
```

[image]

Sadly, it looks terrible because the scales aren't similar.

Comment: @nongkorng Thank you. Now will try to plot ele in right yaxis. seems complicated although in ggplot2.